# Changing AD passwords via ASP.NET. Getting access denied when Application pool is running under privileged user

Tags: active-directory, iis, asp.net

I am trying to build a self-service password reset tool for a test domain.  I am using ASP.NET 4 and IIS 7.

My code:

```
string userDirectoryEntry = "WinNT://domain/" + usermapping[user[1]]
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ADEntryToReset = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(userDirectoryEntry);

ADEntryToReset.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { newPassword });
ADEntryToReset.Properties["passwordExpired"][0] = 1;
ADEntryToReset.CommitChanges();
```

However I am getting access denied when committing the password change. I have changed the Default App Pool to run under an admin account that can change passwords.   Works fine in the Visual Studio debugger.

I have also tried explicitly supplying credentials to the DirectoryEntry object ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.username.aspx)).  This also does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you use LDAP: instead of WinNT:?  Also, can you perform another activity such as modifying an attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the `LDAP` provider instead of the pre-2000 `WinNT` provider, which has some capability limitations compared to `LDAP`.
The `userDirectoryEntry` string should begin with `LDAP://` instead of `WinNT://`

If the msdn example with credentials doesn't work, try initializing the `DirectoryEntry` object with the credentials:

```
new DirectoryEntry(userDN,callerUsername,callerPwd);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2h7eed.aspx